# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 6 ,Here I have two components app.component.ts ,products.component.ts and service file .

Here in products component receiving json response in the ngOnChanges method what I need to do is ,I want to get the json Array length and pass it to the app component .

Ex: if json array lenth is 10 then I will display there are 10 products in this json array response like that .

For me it's working fine .but I got the console error as I mentioned in my title .I have tried some solutions but nothing is fixed this issue.

app.component.ts

```
 this.CartdataService.productCount.subscribe(
  (data :any) =>{
    this.size  = data;
  });
```

Service.

```
public prooductCountUnderCGS = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  productCount = this.prooductCountUnderCGS.asObservable();
```

products.component.ts

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    this.C_code = this.CartdataService.category_code;
    this.G_code = this.CartdataService.group_code;
    this.SG_code = this.CartdataService.subgroup_code;

    this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code,
      this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
        (data : any) => {
          this.size = data.length;
          this.CartdataService.prooductCountUnderCGS.next(this.size);
          this.products = data;
        });

  }
```

can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: give me the explanation before down voting the post

Comment: Hi Zhu, Just I have one question rather than sending length  from product.component , did u try to get that in app.component by this.size = data.length, or directly calculating that in html file by interpolation

Comment: check for data.length, `console.log(data); ` is it null by chance?

Comment: there is no chance for  getting null @eduPeeth

Comment: @Zhu could you check data value by logging or developer console debugger. IMHO `data` is surely null and hence the error.

Comment: yes your right at the time of page load it gets null and the api retuns data only after user do some interactions with that page ...So how can I solve it bro @User3250

Comment: I have an doubt ,I have placed the code which get the length inside the ngOnchanges method then how it throws the console error before it gets triggered @User3250

Comment: @Zhu ngOnChanges gets `Invoked every time there is a change in one of the input properties of the component.` more [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/)

Comment: @Zhu "user do some interactions" then you should make a call only on those particular interactions not on `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check for empty data. debug dat first, see if it's empty. nevertheless, you need a check on data to see. calling length of an object without checking for it's value is risky.

```
 this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code,
      this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
        (data : any) => {
         if(data){ 
          this.size = data.length;
          this.CartdataService.prooductCountUnderCGS.next(this.size);
          this.products = data;}

        });
```

Comment: Bro after page load the json length will be null,it will return data only the user changes some values in the page .So how should I prevent the app from this error @RaminAhmadi

Comment: you need to check to see if data is null before you call any service, otherwise you are passing null which is pointless (correct me if I'm wrong). so you just need to put a check for data, as simple as that :). Updated my answer, btw